# Docker Image for JOnAS (Java EE Application Server)

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image, application-server, jonas

we have a 'legacy' Java application deployed on the JOnAS (old java EE Application Server :[Web Site](https://jonas.ow2.org/) ), and we want to dockerize this application.

I have searched a lot, but I have not found any Docker image for JOnAS server. Therefore, I would be forced to build an image from scratch. Could you please help me on this topic? Thank you.

Note: I specify that the application uses Java 7.